# R basics and questions

Tags: r

I have assigned a value for a variable but still am getting an error message. Kindly help me rectify

Code:
n <- 1000
x <- seq(1,n)
sum(x)

Error: object 'x' not found

Comment: You have to define what object x is

Comment: Try `n <- 1000; x <- seq(1,n); sum(x)
`?

Comment: It should work indeed. Use new line for each command

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use a new line for each command or end each command with semicolon (";")

```
n <- 1000
x <- seq(1,n)
sum(x)
```

Or:

```
n <- 1000; x <- seq(1,n); sum(x)
```